# Texlive: tlmgr can't find referenced package dot2tex

Tags: texlive, dot2tex, dot2texi

I am currently trying to use the [dot2texi](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dot2texi) package, that requires another package, [dot2tex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dot2tex). I first tried to install this latter tool (version 2.8.7)  [from source](http://code.google.com/p/dot2tex/), but some [obscure](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=725066) [python bug](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dot2tex/+bug/1255883) made it unusable. It is claimed to be solved for most Linux distributions, but I use Texlive, thus I can't get the fix though my OS package manager. (And I just switched recently from using my OSes package manager to a Texlive-controlled installation!)

Texlive recommends to use its own package manager (tlmgr), unfortunatly, the following command:

```
tlmgr install dot2tex
```

says:

```
package dot2tex not present in package repository
```

What I don't get is that this package seems to be referenced in CTAN (see second link). How can I solve this issue ?

The command `tlmgr install dot2texi` **did** work, but the command `dot2tex` is not installed.

Comment: It is not a part of repository (yet), the package can be found in PyPi archive, but we cannot install it with `pip`. Use `http://code.google.com/p/dot2tex/downloads/detail?name=dot2tex-2.8.7.zip` or `http://code.google.com/p/dot2tex/downloads/detail?name=dot2tex-2.8.7.tar.gz` and try to install it with EasyInstall.

Comment: `dot2tex` is a Python package, `dot2texi` is a TeX package distributed in official TeX distributions, that's why the installation is working fine.

Comment: @Malipivo Yes, that is exactly what I did. But first it complained about some missing `pyparsing` package. I installed it (`easy_install pyparsing`), and then ran into the bug I linked to (_noncomma stuff, can't tell more, I don't know much about Python).

Comment: I gave up trying to install it on Windows, I ran GraphViz (`dot`) directly, one example of use: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171106/cant-define-environment-whose-macro-code-contains-dot2tex-environment/171159#171159

Comment: I wrote an email to the maintainer of dot2tex if he could help us and give that project among other PyPi projects.

Comment: @Malipivo Thanks for the mail, I wanted to but his website (http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/) is down at the moment. And I am used to calling Graphviz tools directly but I wanted to find a nice way of doing this directly from a Latex source, just as you can do with drawing packages (Tikz).

Answer (score 3):

Kjell Magne fixed that on April 16, 2014. I tested `sudo pip install dot2tex` on Windows (CygWin) and Ubuntu, it is working well. I enclose the original email.

---

Pavel,

Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated the pypi project with source files:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dot2tex/2.8.7

I have not worked on dot2tex for a very long time, but recently I started the process of moving the project to Github. Maybe it will be easier for others to contribute then. The new home of dot2tex will be:
https://github.com/kjellmf/dot2tex
http://dot2tex.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Regards,
Kjell Magne

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but after 1 - cleaning up all previous reference on `dot2tex` on the machine, 2 - running `sudo pip install dot2tex`, I get some strange message, although it claims that installation is ok (see http://pastebin.com/UnHxVijT). But running `dot2tex` gives the same error: `ImportError: cannot import name _noncomma` (see bottom of pastebin).Not at all related to Latex, I assume... For the record, this is with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951748 that seems to be related, not checked yet.

Comment: I would try to upgrade `pyparsing` (maybe `pydot` too) in Python and after that I would try to install `dot2tex` again.

Comment: Thanks, did (in that order) `sudo pip install pydot --upgrade`, `sudo pip install pyparsing --upgrade`, `sudo pip install dot2tex --upgrade`, `dot2tex` => same error as in comment above... Thanks for the efforts, anyway.

Comment: Well, try to uninstall all three packages and try to install just `dot2tex`. I didn't have `pyparsing` installed and it installed it for me on-the-fly.

Comment: Okay, I did `sudo pip unistall dot2tex` and the others, then reinstall as above, still fails. However, I noticed that `pip uninstall` leaves some stuff there: A `locate dot2tex` shows that the binary **stays** in `/usr/local/bin/`. So I did a raw `rm` of all files related to `dot2tex`, proceeded with `pip install` again: still fails at runtime with the `noncomma` message. I think I will leave that aside for the moment...

Comment: I was thinking if you are not running Python3 instead of Python2.7. But I am guessing here.

Comment: `$ python --version` gives `Python 2.7.3`

Comment: @kebs has your problem been solved in the meantime? With `dot2tex` updated on your system. If yes, please give a little note and close this post. Thanks.